# Setting up automatic Cyrillic-Latin conversion in MediaWiki

Tags: internationalization, wiki, mediawiki

I am setting up media wiki for my website and I need to set up automatic conversion between Cyrillic and Latin writing system. Can anyone please tell how can this be done.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [LanguageConverter class](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Writing_systems) in MediaWiki which supposedly does just that, but it is [undocumented](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19044). You might get some help about it on [the MediaWiki mailing list](https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-l).